# Is it acceptable to break a line without creating a new paragraph?

Tags: orthography

Let's say I've got two sentences that are sufficiently related that a new paragraph isn't warranted, but disconnected enough that I start considering putting the last one on a new paragraph.

Is it OK to put a line break after the first sentence, or is this not acceptable in English? Is it paragraphs or continuation of line?

Comment: Either the sentences are related enough to be in the same paragraph or disconnected enough to be in different paragraphs. It's a binary decision. Trying to fudge the issue by using a line-break to create a short line is likely to indicate to the reader that you had forgotten how to deal with a new paragraph.

Comment: What is a line break? Do you mean a carriage return?

Answer (score 1):

Not grammatically.  When writing prose or nonfiction you shouldn't use line breaks, but rather full paragraphs.  Whomever does the final layout will add line breaks to correct or avoid hyphenation errors, avoid columns of white space, or other typographical artifacts distinct to the actual layout.

When you're writing, there is no medium level of separation between a "sentence" and a "paragraph".  Two sentences are either part of the same paragraph or they aren't -- although the rules are different for poetry and signage.

(Also, be aware that an editor may separate a paragraph for purely ascetic reasons.  A paragraph that goes on for three pages may be grammatically correct, but it's physically hard to read and should be separated.)